# How to set data to a view of multi-indexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm a newbie to pandas.
I have a DataFrame that is created by the grabbed data from my database consisting of three columns: `id`, `date`, `value` (only one value of each pair of `id` and `date`).

What I want to do is dividing `value` column by a specific number (`ratio`) for each `id` in a specific `date` range. As size of my data is large (>10M records) I thought setting a multiindex on my DataFrame would be a good idea. And finally here's what I've done:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_history, columns=['id', 'date', 'value'])
df = df.set_index(['id', 'date'])
for id in ids:
    ratio = calc_ratio(id)
    min_date = calc_min_date(id)
    history = df.loc[id]
    history.loc[history.index >= pd.to_datetime(min_date)] /= ratio
    df.loc[id] = history
```

What's the problem? It seems that I've misunderstood the concept of multiindex and `df.loc[id]` gets cleared after the last line. I mean after the setting, `df.loc[id]` returns an empty data frame.

So, what approach should I employ to get my column divided by `ratio`. I'm not sure if it's a good idea or not to use multiindex for my data, but performance is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly how your dataframe looks like then yes, MultiIndex is a good idea. However you don't need a for loop which is usually a good thing in Python.

You DataFrame should look something like this:

```
    id                date  value
0  330 2020-03-30 03:00:00    180
1  330 2020-03-30 04:00:00    360
2  331 2020-03-30 05:00:00    120
3  331 2020-03-30 06:00:00    600
```

So this is what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Generate a sample DataFrame
ids = [330, 330, 331, 331]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids,
                   'date': [datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, h) for h in range(3, 7)],
                   'value': [180, 360, 120, 600]})

# Set index inplace
df.set_index(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)

# Divide values by ratio only at ids where condition "date >= min_date" is satisfied
min_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, 5)
ratio = 2
df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(1) >= min_date] /= ratio

print(df)
```

Which gives you correctly:

```
                         value
id  date                      
330 2020-03-30 03:00:00  180.0
    2020-03-30 04:00:00  360.0
331 2020-03-30 05:00:00   60.0
    2020-03-30 06:00:00  300.0
```

Also note that you can `set_index` without creating a copy of your DataFrame with the keyword argument `inplace=True` which is, of course, better for memory management especially given the size of your DataFrame.

EDIT: If `ratio` and `min_date`have to be evaluated for each `id` then I don't think you can avoid the for loop. The right way to iterate through levels of a MultiIndex is with the method [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) as follows:

```
for id, df_id in df.groupby(level=0):
    min_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, 5)
    ratio = 2
    condition = df_id.index.get_level_values(1) >= min_date
    df.loc[id].iloc[condition] /= ratio
```

which gives the same result as above with the difference that you now have `ratio` and `min_date` in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Francesco. `inplace` was a really important thing that I wasn't aware of. Unfortunately, I didn't mention that `min_date` and `ratio` is calculated for each `id` so the loop cannot be omitted. I mean I also need a selection by id. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Ok then the right way to iterate through levels of MultiIndex is with groupby method. I edited my answer, have a look

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot. but I would appreciate it if you could answer why `history = df.loc[id]
    history.loc[history.index >= pd.to_datetime(min_date)] /= ratio` still doesn't work even if indexing is inplace.

Comment: It doesn't work because to assign a value into a DataFrame you have to use `.loc` and you cannot assign it through `history`. You can still use `history` for checking condition. Basically you can fix your code by replacing `history.loc[history.index >= pd.to_datetime(min_date)] /= ratio` with `df.loc[id].iloc[history.index >= min_date] /= ratio`